# Help to optimize specific SQL query

Tags: performance, optimization, db2, query-performance

I have WORKLOGTABLE which has index on RECORDKEY column.
WORKLOG table has currently 1,200,000 records

When I do the query

```
select * from worklog  where (recordkey= 'SR11034')
```

It returns result very, very quickly.

If I do this query then result is very slow.

```
select * from worklog  where (recordkey= 'SR11034'  )
 or (recordkey in (select wonum from woactivity where origrecordid= 'SR11034' ))
```

So because of this OR it returns results very slowly.
Is there something which I can do make it faster.
Index, or change the query?
I tried instead of IN to have EXISTS clause but then it is even slower.

```
    select * from worklog  where (recordkey= 'SR11034'  )
    or exists (select 1 from woactivity where 
    woactivity.origrecordid='SR11034' and woactivity.wonum=worklog.recordkey)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is woactivity indexed? Try with a join instead of the subquery.

Comment: can you please help me and tell me how to do join query? also please have in mind that I am limited with application restriction that my query MUST start with  SELECT * FROM WORKLOG WHERE  and then I am adding rest of the statement. I can not change that please take that into account. I can add only statement after WHERE...

Comment: also what index would you suggest on woactivity table? just on origrecordid column?

Comment: Why do you have that limitation that your query must start with `SELECT * FROM WORKLOG WHERE`...? That greatly limits your options here.

Comment: If `woactivity` has wide rows, you might get best performance by indexing `origrecordid` and `wonum`, or (if supported in DB2) indexing `origrecordid` and including `wonum`. Note: if `wonum` is an indexed column in a clustered index on `woactivity`, then it may already be included by default. This should let your query ignore the actual `woactivity` table, and treat the index as if it was the table, since it has all the columns needed (this is called a *covering index*).

Comment: @RDFozz can you please provide me more explanation regarding that I should put oboth columns origrecordid and wonum in index? shouldn't I put just origrecordid since it is the only column after the second WHERE clause? Thank you

Comment: Please post the explain plan of the second query, as produced by `db2exfmt`.

Comment: @Dejan - `CREATE INDEX ix_woactivity_origrecid_wonum ON
woactivity(origrecordid, wonum);` `wonum` isn't needed for finding the records - however, since it's in the index, DB2 will be able to use the index alone to get the necessary data, instead of having to use the index to look up records in `woactivity`. Since the full data pages from the `woactivity` don't have to be loaded to memory, the query could (potentially) be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell exactly what is happening without a db2exfmt, you can create one with:

```
#] db2 connect to db
#] db2 "explain plan for ..."
#] db2exfmt -d db -g -1 -o myplan.exfmt
```

Anyhow, here is a shot in the dark:

How does:

```
select wonum from woactivity where origrecordid= 'SR11034'
```

perform? If that is fast, how about:

```
select x.* 
from worklog x
join woactivity y
    on x.recordid = y.wonum
```

If performance is still decent you can try:

```
select x.* 
from worklog x 
join (values 'SR11034'
      union
      select wonum from woactivity where origrecordid= 'SR11034' 
) y (wonum)
    on x.recordid = y.wonum
```

If wonum is disjoint from 'SR11034' you can use `union all`:

```
select * 
from worklog x 
join (values 'SR11034'
      union all
      select wonum from woactivity where origrecordid= 'SR11034' 
) y (wonum)
    on x.recordid = y.wonum
```

and possibly avoid a sort of the derived table y. As far as indexes go, given the queries I suggested:

```
create index ... on woactivity (origrecordid, wonum) ...
```

will help. I assume that worklog.recordid is already indexed.